# How to trimStart multiple strings in LoDash/Underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I've something like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Mr. Foo'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mrs. Bar'
  }
]
```

EDIT:

I'm looking for most efficient way to trimStart the 'Mr.' and 'Mrs.' strings in one fire maybe using LoDash or Underscore to get following:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Foo'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bar'
  }
]
```

I'm looking for a function something like `_.trimStart[ name, ['Mr.','Mrs.'] ]`

Thanks

Comment: A regex replace with for loop or Lodash loop

Comment: *"I'm looking for most efficient way"* - no, you're not. You're looking for someone who writes it down for you.

Comment: @Tomalak I could have wrote `_.trimStart[name, 'Mr.']` and `_.trimStart[name, 'Mrs.']` but that wouldn't be efficient calling two functions for each time. I'm trying to reduce number of function calls.

Comment: I see, but you are worrying too much. Measure it against your real-world data, I bet it won't be slow. Then take 10 times the number of objects you would normally expect and I bet it still won't be slow.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks, that gave me challenge and confidence. I will definitely learn much more. I still have a lot to learn. And I think I made the wrong/confusing question.

Comment: Yeah, you have. :) Resist the temptation to ask performance questions unless you have performance problems (i.e. you have measured it and it is slow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions can do this, lodash however is not necessary.

```
input.forEach(function (item) {
    item.name = item.name.replace(/^(Mrs\.|Mr\.)\s*/i, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
var titles = [];
_.each(people, function(person){
    titles.push(person.name.split('.')[0])
});
```

Comment: That's very interesting solution. I'm sorry I made the half question. Please see the edit.